# React Router and Reactstrap - render path using Breadcrumb

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, reactstrap

I am using reactstrap `Breadcrumb` component as following:

```
<Breadcrumb tag="nav" className="relay-breadcrumb">
  <BreadcrumbItem tag="a" href="#">Dashboard</BreadcrumbItem>
  <BreadcrumbItem tag="a" href="#">Channels</BreadcrumbItem>
  <BreadcrumbItem tag="a" href="#">{match.params.channelName}</BreadcrumbItem>
  <BreadcrumbItem active >{match.params.videoName}</BreadcrumbItem>
</Breadcrumb>
```

When I give the value something like this:

`` href={`/dashboard/channels/${{match.params.channelName}`}} ``

...the redirection seems to work but the whole page reloads.
Please suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`history.push()`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) API of RRv4:

```
<Breadcrumb tag="nav" className="relay-breadcrumb">
  <BreadcrumbItem
    tag="a"
    onClick={() => this.props.history.push(`/dashboard/channels/${match.params.channelName}`)}
  >
    Dashboard
  </BreadcrumbItem>
  {
    /* ....*/
  }
</Breadcrumb>
```

Comment: so shall i remove the href attribute ? i will then it will not behave like link. i mean no mouse pointer change on hover and stuff like that.

Comment: I've updated answer. You can use the `a` tag itself. Or you could use a specially styled button, to make it look like an anchor tag :)